# The file “Cartfile” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, carthage

I am new in IOS development I am trying to load a project from source code in xcode. But when i try to run I was getting error

InAppSettingsKit/IASKAppSettingsViewController.h file not found

I found a solution on internet saying -
Install carthage and run following command:

carthage update --platform iOS

but now on running this update command i am getting this error:-

"The file “Cartfile” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file"

I am new in ios programming so don't have much idea about it. please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: if you are using pods, make sure that you added this line in pod file
    pod 'InAppSettingsKit'    
and try on terminal , pod install then pod update

Answer (score 5):

You'll need a `Cartfile` to get that command to work:

- Make `Cartfile` with your editor of choice
- Add: `github "futuretap/InAppSettingsKit" "master"`
- Run `carthage update --platform iOS`
- Add the framework to your project: *target* -> *General* tab -> *Linked Frameworks & Libraries* section, drag and drop the frameworks from the `Carthage` folder
- Go to *Build Phases* tab and add a new `Run Script` build phase with  the command `/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks`
- Finally click the + under *Input Files* and enter `$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/<the frameworks name>.framework`

There's a good guide on Carthage [on Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109330/carthage-tutorial-getting-started).

Comment: where do i need to create the Cartfile?

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused if you have a old version of `carthage`. The way to fix it is to either update `carthage` or if you can't do it, uninstall and install its latest version